# How to fix dock and desktop icons that are disappearing after sleep

Tags: nvidia, suspend, icons

After my computer sleeps, the desktop and dock icons look like placeholders and the text isn't visible. This also affects the tool bar at the top of the screen. Here is a picture:
[image]

This pretty much makes using the computer for any significant amount of time impossible. Application windows are not affected.

Rebooting fixes the problem. However, it takes 5-15 minutes for me to get back to my working state after a reboot, so this is not something that I can deal with all the time.

1. Is there a way to refresh the desktop and dock so that eveything display correctly?
2. If you have any idea what I might do to fix this, I would love to hear.

Using Ubuntu 20.04 with recent Nvidia drivers on a system 76 machine. Happy to provide any further details which might be helpful.

Comment: Doesn't solve your specific problem, but you could disable sleep (under settings / power) to prevent it happening?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the problem with

1. log in as normal.
2. Press `Alt + F2`.
3. Enter password, if requested.
4. Enter `r` as the command.

The GUI restarted and all icons and text appeared as normal. The problem has not recurred since.

I found the solution at [linuxconfig.org](https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-restart-gui-on-ubuntu-20-04-focal-fossa) which also contains other potential solutions if the above does not work.